# if all these transactions pass then only it will commit.. If any one of the transactions fail it will rollback all the transctons

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, transactions

I was asked this question in interview.. Can you please let me know the answer
 There is one table employee.. With Id name address and salary.. he is eligible for a gift card amounting to 200 and another gift card amount of 100rs.. also he would be charged a tax amount of 50rs..

if all these transactions pass then only it will commit.. If any one of the transactions fail it will rollback all the above transactions.  ie. there are three or more transactions..if even 1 fails all the transactions which are carried out are rolled back and there is no effect on database. If all pass then only database registers the change

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Yes, that is how the concept of commits and rollbacks works. Would you please clarify, what it is you need to understand about it?

Comment: Hi,
The question is how to ensure that all 3 transactions work, then only the transaction is committed else if even one fails rollback all changes to any transaction. How to make such an arrangement work. 
eg. 200rs is added to salary as gift card. If 200rs is added add 100rs more to salary as gift card, if both the above work then substract 50rs as tax from salary. If all the transactions work then only it is committed. If even one fails then all the transactions are rolled back and there is no effect on the database. How does this work? Thats my question

Answer (score 0):

Do it in BEGIN - EXCEPTION - END block. You have to add code for updating salary. If you encapsulate it in procedure make sure, that there is no commit inside.

```
BEGIN
  --add 200rs

  --add 100rs

  --substract 50rs

  COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing transactions in Hibernate or Spring can be done in multiple ways. One, and easiest to implement, would be to create and close the transaction yourself. Like the example below.

```
public void modifyEmployee(String employeeID) {
    Session session = factorySession.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        Employee employee = session.get(Employee.class, employeeID);
        employee.setSalary(employee.getSalary()+200);
        session.update(employee);
        employee.setSalary(employee.getSalary()+100);
        session.update(employee);
        employee.setSalary(employee.getSalary()-50);
        session.update(employee);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
    } finally {
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }       
}
```

As you will see, if any of the transactions fails, then we will catch that error and rollback the transaction. Only if we can finish all updates without failing, then can we commit the transaction.

There is a much better way to do this, but requires more configuration. I would still recommend it, since it makes the transaction management much easier and the code much cleaner, and that would be to use Spring Transactional Manager. This would allow Spring to manage your transactions, so that you don't have to worry about committing or opening, or even closing your session. Also, with the use of the annotation:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

Above any service's methods, should always rollback any changed done inside the method if any of the operations fails, even those that are not database related.

I hope this helps.